# How to change a background when i hover over an image being used as a menu link on the home page

Tags: javascript

I have tried some of the other answers but can't seem to understand the answers well enough to implement. The HTML code for the image I want to use a `mouseover` command to change the background which is simply in my images file.

```
<a href="./car.html">
   <img src="images/index.jpg" id="Image3" alt="" border="0" style="width:153px;height:153px;">
</a>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: <a href="./car.html">
   <img src="images/index.jpg" id="Image3" alt="" border="0" style="width:153px;height:153px;">
</a>

Comment: sorry i know i am a beginner and wanted to try something fancy read other posts i can understand the logic but just can't seem to implement and still getting used to the jargon

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('Image3').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.src = 'newImage.jpg';
}

document.getElementById('Image3').addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    this.src = 'images/index.jpg';
}
```

Comment: do i add this before/inside or after the tag? or inside the anchor?

Comment: @SameerButt It's JavaScript, so you'll need to either put it inside a separate .js file or wrap `<script>` tags around it.